# notification small icon color not the color I set

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm build a notification, setSmallIcon(icon is use white image) and setColor, but I found the color on the phone is not the color i set, the color on the phone is doesn't change, if change red to yellow is ok, but change color value in one type color eg:lightblue darkblue is doesn't change. And if i set color red, the color on the phone is more dark than i set color.
I don't know how to cause this, in virtual phone & sumsung also.

need your help. thx

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_notification)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.notification_icon_color)).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_app_login))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

in manifest set color too

```
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/notification_icon_color"
```

I set color #63B9C7
but on the phone is not #63B9C7

[image: on the phone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building the notification, you can set the color and the icon. If your icon is a pure white image, it'll apply the color for you in the correct spots.

I had this problem too and I found that the problem is with graphical icon. You can solve the problem by using this online tool. open this [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_call_white):

choose your image ( with large dimension ), download the resource and copy them to your project.

and finally set the notification icon using `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ICON_NEW_NAME)`

hope this helps

**Edit**

just a reminder why color may look different on screen , check this [link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42563/why-is-the-color-of-the-same-image-different-when-displayed-on-laptop-and-mobile)

Comment: I tried it according to your method, this problem still occurs.I set color value is #63B9C7, but the color on the phone is not #63B9C7.

Comment: did you create an icon and put it in folder ? you dont have to use : android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/notification_icon_color"

Comment: yeah. I use the online tool format our icon and select a icon in the online tool also still occurs.

Comment: could you explain what you really did ? because i use this tools the create notification icon , and never get this color problem . Nb :i don't anything in the manifest

Comment: I delete manifest notification_color also occurs. I add a photo in the question.

Comment: i see the image , its green but not the same right ? did you know that screen technology may show a different color ?

Comment: yeah. the icon get the color but the color value is not i set. you can see the photo in my question. this is obvious

Comment: did you try in other phone ?

Comment: screen technology may show a different color?  I use virtual phone(pixel xl) & sumsung also occurs.

Comment: yes it shows different color , please read this : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42563/why-is-the-color-of-the-same-image-different-when-displayed-on-laptop-and-mobile

Comment: I have the same problem, and i'm think is that android dont allow some color, maybe for the contrast, if some knows it, please answer this question